# Adding Login logic to current website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, authentication

I am a student working in a co-op position. My project is to add a login page to an existing site (made using FrontPage, I believe) and I am using ASP.NET in vs2010 (VB). I would like to NOT use the login control/membership tools in ASP.NET. I was hoping to make my own login and use session variables to keep track of the users and determine their role off of a field in a table located in the database that currently exists for the site.

Like I said, I am still a student and haven't had a lot of web application experience. I'm not asking for someone to do this for me. I have spent a few days looking over the asp site, the msdn site, and several others but I just can't understand it yet.

Can anyone recommend some really thorough and easy to understand tutorials on session variables and communicating with remote sql databases with ASP.NET?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using custom membership providers(HDI Membership) so that you can start making use of them to make your own login.

Comment: Yes, why don't you want to use membership tools?

Comment: Well to be honest I tried but I have a problem because I am using the full version of Visual Studio and I have the full SQL Server 2005, and I tried to install 2008 R2 but have not been successful so for. So when I attempt to use the login control or WSAT, I get an error that it could not create the buit-in database. and I tried to use a connection string to a seperate database that i am connected to in VS (created in SQL Server full).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please take a look [at this site](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/75/Simple-Login-and-Redirect-for-ASP.NET-and-Access), Mike does a really good job at explaining a real simple login and redirect with the Session. I used it to help a friend some time ago and it went real good.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fit that in and it is working so far.